# Decoding manually a non Codable property of a Codable class

Tags: ios, swift, codable

ClassA conforming to Cadable and has a bunch of properties. One of them is a property of an already existing very complex ClassB that does not conform to Codable. Can I manually decode a non Codable property of a Codable class?

```
struct ClassA: Codable {

   let title: String?
   let subtitle: String?
   let property: ClassB?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case title
      case subtitle
      case property
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        subtitle = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subtitle)
        let JSONString = ?
        property = ClassB.initWith(JSONString: JSONString)
  }

class ClassB: NSObject {

    // Already existing very complex ClassB implemenatation...
}
```

I get error:

> Type 'ClassA' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "manually decode". You can do for ClassB exactly what you did for classA, namely declare it Decodable and implement `init(fromDecoder:)` (and similarly on the Encodable side if you need it). But you cannot make ClassA Codable at all if it has a ClassB property and ClassB isn't Codable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

The error is that you're missing `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` in `ClassA`. `Codable = Encodable & Decodable`, so it's trying to find a way to encode `ClassA` as well. `ClassB` isn't encodable so it can't do it automatically, and you haven't told it how to do it manually either.

If you don't need to encode `ClassA` instances, just make it `Decodable`. Otherwise implement the missing `encode` func.

Or just put in the work and make `ClassB` codable as well. You can use an extension to add it after the fact. If you don't want to do that either, a workaround I've used is to declare a small private codable struct inside `ClassA` like `struct ClassBInfo: Codable`. Use that to get the info you need, then read its properties to init `ClassB`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
struct ClassA: Codable {

   let title: String?
   let subtitle: String?
   let property: ClassB?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case title
      case subtitle
      case property
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        subtitle = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subtitle)
        let JSONString = ?
        property = ClassB.initWith(JSONString: JSONString)
  }

class ClassB: Codable {

    // Already existing very complex ClassB implemenatation...
}
```

Comment: I do not want to change ClassB